# Android - Stop shadow from being dragged out of a zone

Tags: android, drag, shadow, zone

I can't work out on how to stop the shadow from leaving a specific zone when being dragged.

Do you have any idea on how to do that?

Thank's in advance

Comment: zone? shadow? what zone? what shadow? what are you talking about?

Comment: Ok, basically i'm trying to do a controller; I have an image, I can drag it fine but I want it to stop following the finger at some point.

Comment: you konw? when you drag an image, the image draged is called a shadow of the original image

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html#AboutDragShadowBuilder

Comment: Thank you, I saw this link and keep reading but I don't see how to influence the shadow image position while dragging it :(

Comment: ... so no one can answer? Did I miss something?

Comment: try reading this http://lemonycode.blogspot.nl/2012/11/using-custom-dragshadowbuidler-in.html?m=1#!/2012/11/using-custom-dragshadowbuidler-in.html

Comment: Thank you for considering my problem seriously but I'm sorry this link still doesn't explain how to influence the shadow's position (while dragging not before).

Comment: did you override onDrawShadow and check when it is called? i didnt check it but it seems to be called multiple times (but its my guess only)

Comment: I tried using the onDrawShadow and setting a random color and a different shape. It did none of those so I tried spotting it on debug mode and it confirmed that this method is called once on drag started. :(

Comment: so it seems you cannot do what you want, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I finally worked it out with only a onTouch:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        // Handles each of the expected events
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            if (initPosX == 0 && initPosY == 0) {
                initPosX = myImage.getX();
                initPosY = myImage.getY();
            }

            // First finger down
            text.setText("ACTION_DOWN x: " + event.getRawX() + ", y: " + event.getRawY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Last finger to be removed
            text.setText("ACTION_UP x: " + event.getRawX() + ", y: " + event.getRawY());
            myImage.setX(initPosX);
            myImage.setY(initPosY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // A finger moves

            float calc_X = event.getRawX() - initPosX / 2 + myImage.getWidth() / 2;
            float calc_Y = event.getRawY() - initPosY / 2 - myImage.getHeight() / 2;

            if(calc_X > initPosX - delta && calc_X < initPosX + delta)
                myImage.setX(calc_X);

            if(calc_Y > initPosY - delta && calc_Y < initPosY + delta)
                myImage.setY(calc_Y);

            text.setText("X: " + event.getRawX() + "\nY: " + event.getRawY());

            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

It's such a shame though onDragListtener is not capable of doing such a basic stuff... I guess the Android crew did it on purpose.

Special thanks to pskink.